# How to apply non-default Foreground color for DataGridRow when IsEnabled is set to False?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

How to apply non-default Foreground color for DataGridRow when IsEnabled is set to False?
I'm doing it like this, but Foreground color is not changed.

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
      <Style TargetType="DataGridRow" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridRow}}">
           <Style.Triggers>
               <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Name, Converter={StaticResource Converterz}}" Value="true">
                  <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                  <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"></Setter>
               </DataTrigger>        
           </Style.Triggers>
       </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

**EDIT 1**

Ok, I applied style for the DataGrid.CellStyle instead of DataGrid.RowStyle and it worked, but only for cells with TextBlock's. Who can tell me why?

```
<DataGrid.CellStyle>
       <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}" >
           <Style.Triggers>
              <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Name, Converter={StaticResource Converterz}}" Value="true">
                 <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
              <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                 <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                 <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
              </Trigger>
           </Style.Triggers>
       </Style>
 </DataGrid.CellStyle>
```